How to get the default UI layout in RStudio?
I am very new to R and RStudio. RStudio usually had the default user interface split into 4 quadrants. I have updated my computer and now I have only the console interface without the tool bar I am used to.
I want to get the default interface layout back.

I have tried Page set up from File
I have tried package and data icon and package installer
I have tried preference- general
I have tried preference - view- quartz
I have tried workspace-load default workspace I got an error as this file doesn't exist
I have tried to browse workspace - got an empty list

I would be very grateful if someone can tell me how to get the default UI layout back that has source, command and console panes.

Welcome to SO. I have updated your question's tags, formatting, and terminology to better express what you have hopefully meant. Do observe that R and RStudio are two separate things. R is the language and a command-line interface to it. RStudio is the proper GUI that has all the neat features that make R more usable. This question may be more on topic on another Stack Exchange site, even though it is now I think an OK question, just not here. StackOverflow is for software engineering questions, not about how to use software in general.

If you want to get an answer quickly, please take a screenshot of the "broken" RStudio layout. On Windows: 1. press Win-PrtScr (two keys at the same time). 2. The image will be in the Pictures\Screenshots. 3. Open the image with Paint, select the rectangle within which the RStudio window is, press Ctrl-C to copy it into the clipboard. 4. Edit the question on this site, put cursor where you want the image to go, and press Ctrl-V to paste the image.

You may try to uninstall RStudio and install it again. In no case will messing with packages change anything, since those are R packages and they don't influence how RStudio looks. Page Setup is for printing stuff, not about the UI layout either. Maybe try the View or Window menu(s)? That's usually where pane selections would be. I don't have RStudio installed to try it out.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Data Science Stack Exchange under the [rstudio] tag.
